# Choricitos a la sidra -- raw or cured?

Tags: sausages, spanish-cuisine

I was shown this recipe for [choricitos a la sidra](https://cookpad.com/es/recetas/598941-choricitos-a-la-sidra) -- small chorizo sausages cooked in cider. From the pictures it's not obvious if the sausage used is fresh (raw) or cured (ready to eat).

[image] (Image courtesy of https://cookpad.com)

I'm thinking that there's not much sense in boiling cured *choricitos* (if such thing even exists) and the recipe implies raw sausage. However, I'm hoping to learn from those more familiar with Spanish/Portuguese cuisine: what's the usual way of making *choricitos a la sidra* -- from raw or cured *chorizo*?

Comment: There are a few recipes that cook cured chorizo so don't rule it out. This may not be completely authentic (though I've seen recipes in Spanish that imply it is) but it's common in countries where only cured chorizo is available.

Comment: The pciture most certainly appears to resemble small cured sausages to me - the texture and color of the casing is the giveaway. Presumably this version is made that way, and the boiling step softens and sweetens the sausages. (I'm not posting this as an answer because I'm not familiar with the dish and I don't know what's strictly traditional.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical recipe from Asturias uses slightly cured (3-4 days) chorizos. But that's just the traditional recipe, you may want to try different chorizos (there are basically endless different kind of chorizos through Spain) and see what suits you.

Personally, I don't think a completely raw chorizo will withstand the cooking without coming apart, and a more cured one will probably end up being a flavourless dry bunch of meat.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to get my hands on this slightly cured variety. I'm in North America, so this may not be easy. By the way, I tried this with raw chorizo and it turned out all right.

Comment: @mustaccio with raw I really meant "straight from the pig"... it's common to have raw chorizos on "matanzas" here (where they kill the pig and make the chorizos immediately). If you got the chorizo from a store in North America, it's already "slightly cured" :-)

Comment: @mustaccio btw, the spanish word for cider is "sidra" (with an "s"), not "cidra" :-)

Comment: Just to close off this argument, I finally tried this with fully cured chorizos and the result was not as good as with "raw" (store-prepared, so probably 1-2 days cured) sausages -- the apple flavour infused meat to a much lesser extent, and the sauce/sirup at the end of cooking was not so rich in flavours either, so from my limited experience it appears that the fresher (raw-er) the sausage, the better the result will be.